# How to collect collect data from Jquery ajax response to html?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter and Jquery ajax for calling data from mysql and send to html form.

Problem: I Don't know how to call data from **res** object.

Here is my contrller

```
public function select_post(){

        $data = $this->ads_m->get_post('ads',array('user_id'=>  $this->user->user_id()));
        IF($data){
            foreach($data as $row ){

                $response = array(
                    'name'=>$row->name,
                    'price'=>$row->price,
                    'addr'=>$row->des,
                    'img'=>$row->img,
                    'status'=>$row->status,
                );
                echo json_encode(array('res'=>$response));
            }
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array('res'=>FALSE));
        }
    }
```

And here is Model function

```
public function get_post($from, $where = False) {

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from($from);
        if ($where) {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $q = $this->db->get();
        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            return $q->result();
        }
    }
```

And this is Ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo base_url('ads/select_post'); ?>',
         data: {},
         dataType: "json",
         cache: false,
         success: function (data) {
         console.log(data.['res']['name']);
       }
    });
```

});

and I get the result as below

```
{"res":{"name":"dfasdfas","price":"0","addr":"sadfdfasdfasdf","img":"","status":"1"}}{"res":{"name":"Heng"
,"price":"0","addr":"asdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasd
fasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfasdfasdfasdf"
,"img":"","status":"1"}}{"res":{"name":"asdDasdA","price":"0","addr":"ASDasdASD","img":"","status":"1"
}}{"res":{"name":"asdfas","price":"0","addr":"dfasdf","img":"","status":"1"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// First change the response 
public function select_post(){

```
    $data = $this->ads_m->get_post('ads',array('user_id'=>  $this->user->user_id()));
    IF($data){
        var $responseArray = [];
        foreach($data as $row ){

            $response = array(
                'name'=>$row->name,
                'price'=>$row->price,
                'addr'=>$row->des,
                'img'=>$row->img,
                'status'=>$row->status,
            );
            array_push($responseArray, $response);

        }
        echo json_encode($responseArray);
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('res'=>FALSE));
    }
}

//Then used below code to get the response in ajax
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url('ads/select_post'); ?>',
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
       success: function (data) {
          $.each(data, function(item) {
          console.log(item.name);
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: in above code just change the IF with if...it will work surly

Comment: Now I trying your code again and again wait. because I think you code maybe better

Comment: Use $responseArray = []; instead of var $responseArray = [];

Comment: The same thing, You know if I don't used foreach loop for Json data it will ok and work fine but the problem when I echo Json inside of foreach loop it will not send any data to console

Comment: Now it is working is you correct your $.each function as below

$.each(data, function(item, val) {
                                    console.log(item+":"+val.name);
                                });

Answer (score 0):

In you controller do json_encode after for loop

```
foreach($data as $row ){
    $response[] = array(
        'name'=>$row->name,
        'price'=>$row->price,
        'addr'=>$row->des,
        'img'=>$row->img,
        'status'=>$row->status,
    );
}
echo json_encode(array('res'=>$response));
```

And then in ajax check whether data.res returns the data or not
If it is returning data then apply for loop on it to take "name" assigned

Comment: or `data['res']['name']`

Comment: TypeError: data.res is undefined
error source line:
 

console.log(data.res.name);

Comment: Yes If i used echo json_encode(array('res'=>$response)); outside loop it will show me one row but if i used inside of loop it will not show me

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public function select_post(){

        $data = $this->ads_m->get_post('ads',array('user_id'=>  $this->user->user_id()));
        if($data){
            foreach($data as $row ){

                $response = array(
                    'name'=>$row->name,
                    'price'=>$row->price,
                    'addr'=>$row->des,
                    'img'=>$row->img,
                    'status'=>$row->status,
                );
                echo json_encode(array('res'=>$response));
            }
        }else{
            echo json_encode(array('res'=>FALSE));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh my god this is my orginal function but why not it is work?

Comment: Oh this is not correct because it will select only one row

Comment: if I put echo json_encode(array('res'=>$response));   this in loop it will not show any errors and resulte on console.log(data.res.name);
                                console.log(data['res']['name']);